# Open view controller programatically and dont see navigation bar. Swift 3

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar

On my story board I have a collection view controller embedded in a navigation controller. Now from the cell of the collection view, I programaticly open the second view controller (called TwoPicsViewController), like this:

```
 let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

            let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TwoPicsViewController") as! TwoPicsViewController


            self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

However when my TwoPicsViewController opens, I don't see the navigation bar at all. On the story board I connected the TwoPicsViewController to the first view controller with a segue show.

Am I missing something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To push a new `UIViewController` to the navigation stack you should use:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
```

Instead of:

```
self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not putting the new vc on the navigation stack, try this:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue Name", sender: nil)
```

And on Storyboard select the Segue, attributes inspector, identifier = "Segue Name"